# How to split up string on first whitespace occurance in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, regex, postgresql

I have column in PostgreSQL DB and I would like to make a Flyway migration to split the full-name into the first_name and last_name based on the first occurrence of the white-space. There are some rouge rows where there is either only one word or several of them.  E.g.:

```
| fullname         |
| ---------------- |
| Admin            |
| Jon Doe          |
| Vincent Van Gogh |
```

and I want to migrate column fullname into:

```
| first_name | last_name |
| -----------|---------- |
| Admin      |           |
| John       | Doe       |
| Vincent    | Van Gogh  |
```

**Incorrect solution:** 
I have tried several regular expression in order to find correct regex to split the string on first white-space occurrence. Unfortunately all were  unsuccessful. Can anybody help me to find proper regex for splitting the string on the first occurrence of white-space? Or maybe there is better way using other PostgreSQL method than regexp_split_to_array()?

```
UPDATE users
    SET first_name = (regexp_split_to_array(users.full_name, '\s+'))[1], 
        last_name  = (regexp_split_to_array(users.full_name, '\s+'))[2],
```

In case of '\s+' regex, array is created with 3 elements and to last_name is padded only the 2nd element in case of Vincent Van Gogh.

```
| first_name | last_name |
| -----------|---------- |
| Admin      |           |
| John       | Doe       |
| Vincent    | Van       | <- Missing Gogh surname
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may use [`substring`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP):

```
UPDATE users
    SET first_name = substring(users.full_name, '^\S+'),
        last_name = substring(users.full_name, '^\S+\s+(.*)'),
```

The `^\S+` pattern matches 1 or more non-whitespace chars at the start of the string.

The `^\S+\s+(.*)` pattern matches a string that starts with 1+ non-whitespace chars at the start, then has 1+ whitespace chars, and then captures into Group 1 any amount of 0+ chars. The parenthesized part, the capturing group pattern, is what `substring` will return.

> But if the pattern contains any parentheses, the portion of the text that matched the first parenthesized subexpression (the one whose left parenthesis comes first) is returned.